# Insert picture into beamer presentation with white background

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I have found the following solution to insert a large picture as a new slide:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[keepaspectratio, width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{img}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Since the image is not completely filling out the space, the frame decoration peeks through at the sides.

How can I add a white background (resp. remove the frame decoration) so that the frame is no longer visible?

Comment: Could you provide a graphical example to complement your explanation=?

Comment: Additionally a complete compiliable [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) would be useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Approach 1:

remove the frame decorations with the `plain` frame option

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[keepaspectratio, width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

#### Approach 2:

As you are already using tikz to position your image, you could fill the whole slide with a solid colour (red in the example below, change it to whatever background colour you use for your slides)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
   \fill[red] (current page.south east) rectangle (current page.north west);
  \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[keepaspectratio, width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```